# How to describe an object used to protect from evil eye?

Tags: word-usage

a pendant , a doll or a lemon n chilly are hanged by people at the entrance of their home , shop or at the front of their vehivle .Can we call such objects as emulet or talisman?  Languages also go hand in hand with the culture.Im not sure if such usages are in practice among the native speakers of English.

Comment: You are right that such an object is not part of the culture for most native English speakers. The Cambridge Dictionary defines **talisman** as "an object believed to bring good luck or to keep its owner safe from harm", though I would regard it only as something that brings good luck. According to the dictionarly **amulet** is the correct word to use, but i don't think thatmany english speakers know what the word really means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While both *amulet* and *talisman* could be considered to be a means of protection from someone or something (based on belief), the words themselves just mean, in general, a piece of jewellery (in the one case) or an object that brings good fortune only (in the other case), rather than actually acting to protect against evil.

A better word that describes the nature of protection specifically is [**ward**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ward):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>    **7** : a means of defense : PROTECTION

The same object can be described both in terms of its mundane existence and this sense of protection.

Thus:

> The doll is a *ward* against evil.